# Please help with bicycle identification

Tags: identify-this-bike

Can you please help me identify this bike. I think it is aluminium as it is only 9kg all up. I suspect it is quite good as it has very good gear such as Shimano Ultegra. I appreciate your help.

[image: Bicycle side view]

[image: Bicycle Rear view]

[image: Front view]

Comment: If you are looking at a bike with Ultegra components, then this looks like a late 80s model due to the downtube shifters instead of STI in the brake levers.  How many gears does it have?

Comment: Please do the magnet test - I think you might find that's a steel frame, so will attract a magnet.   Tubes look  WAY too small to be 90s aluminium, and downtube shifters imply 80s or early 90s.   Another possibility, its a more modern steel bike custom built to older standards, hence the curved stays which is post-2000.    Also the rear seat stays attaching below the saddle  - another modern design not 80s.    In any way, its a gorgeous wee bike and I'd ride it if I were smaller.  Enjoy riding it!

Comment: It appears to have a triple crank which makes it even more interesting.

Comment: Please note that it’s common for bike thieves to repaint a bike and replace components to hide its origin. So please do run the frame number through BikeIndex.org or other serial checker — and don’t forget to register it if it’s in the clear!  Beautiful bike!

Comment: Yeah pretty bike! The head tube is quite short, I wonder if that’s a clue to anyone? You might need a longer cage rear derailleur with that triple, looking at the slack in the chain

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  I have checked the indexes to see if it's stolen and it isn't.  I actually bought it at an op shop.  I'd like to sell it to fund purchasing a bike or three for my children but am having trouble establishing a value as I don't know the make.  I didn't know steel could be so light.  I will do the test.  I'm also trying to establish the size.  CT is about 50cm 19.5" and the wheels appear to be 26 "

Comment: Wheels might be smaller to suit the frame, could be a nudge towards custom frame if so? Let us know what numbers you find on the wheels/tyres, anything including 622, 584 or 559 for example. Don’t expect a solid valuation because they are quickly obsolete and discouraged, but we can likely help describe the bike to help you

Comment: No absolute valuation will be possible for such a machine. Valuations are often difficult even for recent bikes from major manufacturers where the model and year are known. It's worth what you can persuade someone to pay you for it.

Comment: Lovely little bike, but suspect its resale value is lingering somewhere close to 'Free to a good home'

Comment: @ChrisMacman your bike's chain appears to be excessively long.  Someone's changed the chain and has not removed the extra links.  At a guess it needs 4 halflinks removed to stop the derailleur tucking up like a pink flamingo leg.  Also, you need bartape to hold those brake cables better.

Comment: @ChrisMacman sorry - valuations are off topic here.  But its certainly not a junk bike.  If it were bigger I'd totally ride it.  This could be great for a teen who wants to road-cycle - smaller road bikes are really uncommon, even with downtube shifters (which could be replaced by brifters easily enough)

Comment: Looks like a collection of mismatched part put together by someone who didn't exactly know what they were doing. The frame could be early 2000s from the time when cable stops were screwed to downtube shifter mounts and threadless headsets weren't standard. Then someone put in actual down tube shifters, cranks that look like they are from a hybrid bike, brake levers that are certainly from 2000s and really badly installed and wheels that look more 2010s.

Comment: Thanks again for all your comments.  I'm still researching

Comment: If I wanted to put integrated shifters onto it as that's what my son would require for it, could I do that?  Would I need to get ultegra to match the ultegra rear derailler?